# Hessian Matrix Identity

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to see why the following identity is true. I've lifted it from an exercise in Miles Reid Algebraic Geometry. I'm having difficult deriving it and feel there might be a simple line or two to do it?

If $x_i'$ = $\sum a_{ij}x_j$ is a projective coordinate change with A = $ (a_{ij})$ a nonsingular (n+1) $ \times $ (n+1) matrix and if g(x') = f(Ax), where f is a form of degree d in $x_0, x_1, ... x_n$prove that the Hessian matrix transforms as $$ H(g, \textbf{x'}) = A^tH(f, \textbf{x})A$$

Comment: You can get a complete answer to your question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492858/jacobian-matrix-and-hessian-matrix-identity

Comment: I looked at that but I don't see how to change from the jacobian to the matrix A above.

Comment: The jacobian there is the matrix of transformation from $X$ to $Y$ - exactly what you have here $x^\prime$ from $x$.