# Change of Coordinate and Chain Rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I think I am confused about something very fundamental about change of coordinates and how it affects computing the derivatives, and I would really appreciate some clarification. Let me set up my question appropriately:

Suppose we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and I want to compute its gradient $\nabla_{x}f(x_0)$ at some point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. However, the expression of $f$ is very complicated in this coordinate system, and I know that in another coordinate system described by $x \mapsto y$, where we have a nice invertible linear function $Ax=y$, the gradient $\nabla_{y}f(y_0)$ in that coordinate system has a very simple form. I want to make use of this simple $\nabla_y f(y_0)$ to compute $\nabla_{x}f(x_0)$. However, it seems like a simple application of the chain rule does not really give me what I want, because
$$\nabla_x f(x_0) = \nabla_x f(AA^{-1}x_0) = A^T\nabla_yf(AA^{-1}x_0) = A^T\nabla_yf(x_0)$$

Now I am stuck. Is there no hope of making use of the gradient in one coordinate system to compute the gradient in another coordinate system like I am trying to do? Am I making some basic mistakes? Are there alternatives? Any clarification/help is appreciated!

BTW, I am also curious about a related problem on Hessian calculation. In [Hessian Matrix Identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917497/hessian-matrix-identity?noredirect=1&lq=1), the following is claimed to hold:
$$ H(g,x') = A^tH(f, x)A, \text{ where } g(x')=f(Ax)$$
This is not correct is it? I mean take a simple $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x')=f(ax)=(ax)^2$, we have
$$\frac{d^2g}{dx'}(x')=2, \text{ while } a\times\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}(x)\times a=2a^2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, with $y_i=\sum_j A_{ij}x_j$, we see that

$$A_{ij}=\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}$$

Hence, from the chain rule we have

$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i}=\sum_j (A^T)_{ij}\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial y_j}\tag1$$

Denote $f(x)=f(A^{-1}y)=g(y)$.  Then, we can write

$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i}=\sum_{j} (A^T)_{ij}\frac{\partial g(y)}{\partial y_j}$$

which can be expressed compactly as

$$\nabla_x f(x)=A^T \nabla_y g(y)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. I do have some more questions, I would really appreciate it if you can clarify them for me. First, I don't really follow the second last line of equations, because isn't it suppose to be $(A^{-1})_{ij}$? Second, and this is more important, could you elaborate on how the result you showed relates to my problem of using gradient computed in one coordinate system to evaluate the gradient in another? Is this function $g$ my $f$ in the transformed coordinates $y$? How do I really interpret your result?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: By the "second last line of equations," did you mean $$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i}=\sum_{j} (A^T)_{ij}\frac{\partial g(y)}{\partial y_j}\,?$$If so, note that we have $$\frac{\partial f(A^{-1}y)}{\partial x_i}=\sum_j \frac{\partial f(A^{-1}y)}{\partial y_j}\frac{\partial y_j}{\partial x_i}=\sum_j (A^T)_{ij}\frac{\partial f(A^{-1}y)}{\partial y_j}=A^T\nabla_y f(A^{-1}y)$$And we denoted $g(y)=f(A^{-1}y)$

Comment: Ah yes I was being stupid. But could you throw some light on my second question (OK series of questions..)? I really want to know how to interpret this result, and if the goal I am trying to achieve (stated in problem statement) could use the result. It's been a long time since I've done calculus, I hope you understand..

Comment: Yes, $g(y)=f(A^{-1}y)$.  So, the gradient in the $x$ system is the product of $A^T$ with the gradient in the $y$ system.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. I need to think about this more. Thanks again!